# Three.js render multiple composers

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, shader

i was trying to render multiple composers like :

```
var wt = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( Width, Height, rtParameters);
var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, wt);
var renderPass =  new THREE.RenderPass(part_of_scene, camera);
composer.addPass(renderPass);



var wt2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( Width, Height, rtParameters);
var composer2 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, wt2);
var renderPass2 =  new THREE.RenderPass(another_part_of_scene, camera);
composer2.addPass(renderPass2);
```

and for both renderpasses :

```
renderPass.clear = false;
renderPass.clearDepth = true;


var effect1 = new THREE.ShaderPass(blur_shader);
effect1.renderToScreen = true;
composer1.addPass(effect);

var effect2 = new THREE.ShaderPass(sepia_shader);
effect2.renderToScreen = true;
composer2.addPass(effect);
```

and in the render loop :

```
composer1.render(delta);
composer2.render(delta);
```

the problem is that only the composer2 renders, and i think it renders on top of the composer1, cauz when i `//composer2.render(delta);` the composer1 renders normally, so i am asking, why this behaviour? and how can i render the composer 2  on top of composer1 whithout clearing composer1, i mean i want them both to show up.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use 1 composer and just add the multiple passes to it? Bc that is the sort of standard use case...

Comment: i want to do a sepia shader to a part of the scene and and a blur effect to another part(without it beign sepia) this is where the problem lies...